# Use JQuery to access nested CSS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

FINAL EDIT: Sleep deprivation does exist. I apologize for this question as it was stupid and unnecessary. I was trying to update the CSS before the content was loaded. This has been solved.

EDIT: Since this explanation was too hard, can someone please provide an example of how to update the CSS background-image for the below using JQuery?

ALSO: I have tried the below methods as well with no results:

```
$('#venuesInfoTable #venuesInfoData h3').css('background-image', 'url(' + featureProperties.venuePic + ')');

$('#venuesInfoData h3').css('background-image', 'url(' + featureProperties.venuePic + ')');

$('#venuesInfoTable h3').css('background-image', 'url(' + featureProperties.venuePic + ')');
```

I am trying to update the background image of a Header using JQuery. But i cannot figure out the way to access the css.

I have tried using the following Jquery:

```
$('#venuesInfoData .h3').css('background-image', 'url("")');
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="venuesInfoTable" class="clear">
  <div class="data" id="venuesInfoData">
    <h3><span>$29</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><b>TEXT HERE</b></li>
      <li><b>TEXT HERE</b></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="">Sign up</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#venuesInfoTable #venuesInfoData h3 {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: 400px 200px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 394px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;     
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a clear problem statement? You haven't explicitly mentioned what *isn't* working - as far as we can tell, this is all proper syntax and should hypothetically work. You should also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also your selector is for `<anyElement class="h3">` not `<h3>` tag

Comment: Looks like a typo

Comment: The problem is that the JQuery statement IS NOT updating the URL to an actual value that I am specifying

Comment: @TannerA. Refer to @charlieftl's comment. `.h3` is [not the same](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/dsv70yfo/3/) as `h3`. :)

Comment: `'tagName'`, `'.className'`, `'#id'`, `'[attribute]'`

Comment: Please note the comment from @charlietfl above - `$('#venuesInfoData .h3')` will try to select an element _with a class of `"h3"`_, whereas you probably want to select the _element_ `<h3>`-- you would want `$('#venuesInfoData h3')` instead.

Comment: Please see updated edits. I have tried the above methods.

Comment: Does the element exist at the time you try to change the css? Provide a [mcve] that displays the issue

Comment: Please post how a url to an image is derived from `featureProperties.venuePic`.

Comment: First of all you should use $(' #venusInfoData h3') selector. The syntax looks fine. Can you share the Javascript code prior to changing the background image? Please verify the URL value accessed from the object is correct. Check whether the document is ready before the update.

Comment: What is a *nested CSS selector* supposed to be?

Answer (score -1):

try changing:

```
$('#venuesInfoData .h3').css('background-image', 'url("")');
```

to:

```
$('#venuesInfoData > h3').css('background-image', 'url("")');
```